# dlib matrix append column

Tags: c++, matrix, dlib

I've defined a column matrix in dlib like this

```
int dim = 2;
int dbsize = 1;
matrix<float> db(dim, dbsize);
```

I'm trying to append a new column to db.  However, I'm not able to!
I've tried the following but to no avail (m is a column matrix)

```
set_colm(db, 0) = m;  
//  It replaces column 0
```

> colmat:
>   0.62 
>   0.4
>
> dbbefore:
>   0.840188 
>   0.394383  (2,1)
>
> db_after:
>   0.62 
>    0.4  (2,1)

```
set_colm(db, 1) = m;
//  Instead of adding new column, it updates last cell
```

> colmat:
>   0.62 
>    0.4
>
> dbbefore:
>   0.840188 
>   0.394383  (2,1)
>
> db_after:
>   0.840188 
>       0.62  (2,1)

Is there a way to append a new column to a matrix?